# How to split strings separated by many semicolons in R?

Tags: r, text, strsplit

My desire is to know the length of a certain text separated by `;` which comes after any number. In the text named `txt` below, I don't want to consider the first two semicolons. To get the length, the `;` comes after `6`, `5` should be considered. I mean the code should **lookbehind some number(s)** to consider the appropriate `;`.

```
library(stringr)
txt <- "A;B; dd (2020) text  pp. 805-806; Mining; exercise (1999), ee, p-123-125; F;G;H text, (2017) kk"
```

`lenghths(strsplit(txt,";"))` gives me `8`. In my case, however, it should be `3`. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We can use a regex lookaround to match a `;` that succeeds a digit (`(?<=[0-9])`) and get the `lengths`

```
lengths(strsplit(txt, "(?<=[5-6]);", perl = TRUE))
#[1] 3
```

---

Or using `str_count`

```
library(stringr)
str_count(txt, '[5-6];') + 1
#[1] 3
```

Comment: Can it be possible to look behind the numbers or closing bracket `)`?

Comment: @Gadaa theere is no closing brakcet before the `;`in your example

Comment: Sure! I'm thinking in the presence of `)`.

Comment: @Gada e.g. in here `dd (2020) text  pp. 805-806`. Are you looking for any `)`

Comment: @Gadaa Do you need `lengths(lapply(strsplit(txt, "(?<=[5-6]);", perl = TRUE), function(x) grep('\\)', x)))#
[1] 3`

Comment: In some of my text, there is a case like `dd (2020) text 8(33)`.

Comment: @Gadaa which one should be matched

Comment: @Gadaa If it is to match the four digits, `lengths(lapply(strsplit(txt, "(?<=[5-6]);", perl = TRUE), function(x) grep('\\(\\d{4}\\)', x)))`